# Why Typescript does not infer mixin class

Tags: typescript

I found this error in my code: **Property 'debug' does not exist on type 'HardToDebugUser'.**. Typescript had haven't infer mixin class. Right? Explain to me. Thank you very much.

```js
type ClassConstructor<T> = new(...args: any[]) => T
function withEzDebug<C extends ClassConstructor<{
    getDebugValue(): object
}>>(Class: C) : C{
    type Hi = typeof Class;

    return class extends Class {
        constructor(...args: any[]) {
            super(...args)
        }
        debug() {
            let Name = Class.constructor.name
            let value = this.getDebugValue()
            return Name + '(' + JSON.stringify(value) + ')'
        }
    }
}
class HardToDebugUser {

    constructor(private name: string, private grade: number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    getDebugValue() {
        return {
            name: this.name,
            grade: this.grade
        }
    }
}
let User = withEzDebug(HardToDebugUser);
let userWithDebug = new User("hi", 1);
userWithDebug.debug();
```

How to infer mixin class in Typescript.

Answer (score 1):

Your `withEzDebug` function **explicitly** says that its return type is `C`, the type of the class passed in. Not `C + ___`, just `C`. So of course, that's what TypeScript uses.

If you want the return type to be inferred from the anonymous class, take off that return type annotation *(I've also removed the unused `Hi` type [which was just `C` anyway] :-) )*:

```typescript
type ClassConstructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

function withEzDebug<
    C extends ClassConstructor<{
        getDebugValue(): object;
    }>
>(Class: C)/* >>>No return type annotation here<<< */ {
    return class extends Class {
        constructor(...args: any[]) {
            super(...args);
        }
        debug() {
            let Name = Class.constructor.name;
            let value = this.getDebugValue();
            return Name + "(" + JSON.stringify(value) + ")";
        }
    };
}

class HardToDebugUser {
    constructor(private name: string, private grade: number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    getDebugValue() {
        return {
            name: this.name,
            grade: this.grade,
        };
    }
}
let User = withEzDebug(HardToDebugUser);
let userWithDebug = new User("hi", 1);
userWithDebug.debug();
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgNgQwM5JgewHZOAJwK4DGwaOAPACoB8UAvFBhAO5QAUAdBwjgOZIBcUBBhABtALoBKWtXIBuAFDyAZngxEAlpiiN1wABYBRAF4ARCACM83UvKh3YUCAA9gEDABMksRCnRZchMRkAN629uHcEMBmltwAaghweBAsEgJo5gBWEEQK4QC+lPKULPDI-LASAPQAVFCUDQByaFA4UXg4GFCgkIIYGGjACMCaXXoQbaRTUDVVUKHhbcAdXQQ+Xs6uHl5lKPNh4XYEmNj4RCTsnDwVQqKS+4ePUEh4kDiXbFy8EnlP+QeHdwWKypB5PcJwKJQRoIAC20DouyQbGO-jOQTYGDhEF+4LskOAUAAbolkrRunp1MjItFgfFSSkfgDwUsVtDsVAANRQABELB5XKgACkAMoAeUabFO6gw3HUShALBJSQgUm5PIkPNxh3+BQU-3ka3KUAAElx3OQ0DErABVJATMFHE4Bc7vMA4dQk1z0bECaWygA0UHdnuG0G4OAQQIEGDwsPMEykCye+ipmI5dCx8O14VT1MjQPJEajOIBBoiUWt9JVoOTj1ZnUdeKzEAEefT8IDzKexejFLTvYgXfB+W1-3+BKgdoddB0+mMVZYZpwFqtdOnOCZk7w9pwAHVdHoq+SGMwN-zKTygwBGJk7iYH-RVthA2KpWRAA)